# Show popup or smart dialog once on screen load

Tags: acumatica

I want to show a popup with some message to user whenever screen gets loaded for the first time for each record.

For example when Sales Order screen is loaded for particular sales order, it should show the popup only once. Then user navigates to a next sales order, it should again show the popup for that particular sales order only once.

I have written the code in constructor and RowSelected event, but it does not has the Current record. That is `CRCurrentCaseNotes` is always null in both this events. However, with the button (`ViewNotes` in below code sample), it works.

```html
[PXViewName("CRCurrentCaseNotes")]
[PXCopyPasteHiddenView]
public PXSelect<Note,
 Where<CRCase.caseID, Equal<Current<CRCase.caseID>>>> CRCurrentCaseNotes;

public CRCaseMaintExtension()
 : base()
{
 if (CRCurrentCaseNotes.Current != null)
 {
     CRCurrentCaseNotes.AskExt();
 }
}

protected virtual void CRCase_RowSelecting(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
{
 var caseRow = (CRCase)e.Row;
 if (caseRow == null) return;

 if (CRCurrentCaseNotes.Current != null)
 {
     CRCurrentCaseNotes.AskExt();
 }
}

// SAME CODE WORKS WITH THE BUTTON CLICK
public PXAction<CRCase> viewNotes;

[PXUIField(DisplayName = "View Notes")]
[PXButton]
protected virtual IEnumerable ViewNotes(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    if (CRCurrentCaseNotes.Current != null)
 {
     CRCurrentCaseNotes.AskExt();
 }

    return adapter.Get();
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try to show the dialog when the primary DAC key field is modified:

```
protected void CRCase_CaseID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
   CRCase case = e.Row as CRCase;

   if (case != null && case.CaseID != null && !e.ExternalCall)
   {
      // Show dialog
   }
}
```

If there's no other way you could use JavaScript to show/hide the SmartPanel:

```
document.getElementById("<%=SmartPanelID.ClientID %>").style.display = 'block';
```

**EDIT**:

Dialog can only be shown from an action event handler (FieldUpdated won't work) or from JavaScript. To open dialog when the page open, you can try hooking DocumentReady event in JavaScript and call the Acumatica action from JavaScript too: px_alls['ds'].executeCallback('ActionName');

Comment: I have tried `FieldUpdated`, `FieldUpdating` and `FieldSelecting` events. None of them are getting executed when Case screen gets loaded first time neither when I navigate cases.